# Looping if statement with index and match functions

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, match

I'm trying to write a VBA code and I'm at a loss. I have a certain survey depth and a range of depths. I need to find the depth interval the survey falls within and then subtract the survey depth from the starting depth. At the next survey, I need to do the same but also add the remainder of the previous survey.

The data looks like this:

[image: Table]

Basically what I want to do is:

```
if S1 > d1 and S1 < d2 then s1-d1
if s2 > d3 and s2 < d4 then (s2-d3) + (d2-s1)
' and so on.
```

However, the survey depths will not always line up with the depths so I need some type of match function that will correlate the survey with the correct depth range.

Comment: I am failing to see that this would be correct: (s2-d3) = (d2-s1), by the way your start and end depths stop being continuous after row 3, you are "skipping" depth.  Those are strange choices for depth intervals, are they related to depth over a time interval?  I am familiar with the type of data you are looking at, but I am not familiar with your data set.

Comment: Sorry. I corrected it. Supposed to be + not =

The depth intervals are not supposed to be continuous. The depth intervals indicate a time period of slide drilling. I have filtered out the data to only show me the intervals of interest. The data set does include the "skipped" depth intervals but I am not interested in those.